# Google sheets dynamic copy/paste

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, google-sheets-formula, copy-paste

I was doing a copy of data from one google sheet to another google sheet with references from another google sheet cells. However, when I insert a new row in between and add data in the original sheet, it doesn't get reflected in the new sheet. How can I make such a dynamic copy-paste in which newly added row can be reflected in the new sheet?

Comment: Will you please give some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Importrange` formula

As I understand, you are trying to copy data from `Google-sheet1` to `Google-sheet2`

use this formula in cell `A1` the `Google-sheet2` where you want the data from the original sheet i.e. from `Google-sheet 1`

> `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")`

The only change you need to make is to change the `URL` mentioned in the formula to the `URL` of your `Google-sheet1`. Just copy-paste your sheet `URL` here. And define the Range - like what data from `google-sheet1` should you copy to `google-sheet2` (eg.A1 to E100) So, all the data in this range will be copied to your new sheet.

By doing this, every change you make in `original-sheet` should be copied in your `second sheet`.